# Native android UI component, make it an npm package

Tags: android, npm, react-native

I followed [this](https://reactnative.dev/docs/0.63/native-modules-setup) to create a native Android UI component (let's call it `mypackage`) for my react-native project. The component contains Java code + JavaScript code.

How can I make / bundle up my source code (both Java + JavaScript) into an npm package so that I may publish and for everyone to simply use it by `npm install <mypackage>`?

Posts like [this](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-publish-a-react-native-component-to-npm-its-easier-than-you-think-51f6ae1ef850/) don't even mention the Java-side code. Confusing.

Comment: Not sure if you knew about [Android Library files - AAR](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library) which relates to https://github.com/callstack/react-native-builder-bob#aar

Comment: Thanks, @MorrisonChang. I don't fully understand AAR, but I doubt this is the common approach for creating a React Native library. My aim is to create a RN library (an npm package, can be used for both iOS + android), except currently I only have Android side code.

Comment: Relevant: https://medium.com/wix-engineering/creating-a-native-module-in-react-native-93bab0123e46